# Relation between independence of 2 random variables and their covariance

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, expected-value

I know that if 2 random variables are indepedent, then E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)

IN such a case COv(XY)=E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)=0

But if Cov(XY)=0 then X and Y may or may not be independent.

But in given example, how to say 2 random variables U and V are independent or not

X~ random variable and $f(x)= 1+x, -1 <x \leq 0 ; \\ 1-x , 0<x<1, \\ 0 ,otherwise$

> To check whether U=X and $V=X^2$ are independent or not

My attempt:

$E(x)=0 = E(x^3)$

$E(x^2)=1/6$

$E(UV)=E(x^3)=0$

$E(x)E(X^2)=0$ and also $Cov(U,V)=0$

My doubt is whether U and V are independent or not as i am getting E(UV)-E(U)E(V)=0 and also Cov(U,V)=0

Comment: You proved they are uncorrelated. As you know, this does not imply they are independent. So you need to do more work. You may want to compute a conditional probability or expectation of one given the other.

Comment: sir kindly elaborate. I agree that V is funtion of u, it means they are dependent. But there is a theorem that if E(UV)=E(U)E(V) then 2 random variables are independent right? pls clarify

Comment: There is no such general theorem. You already told us there is no such theorem in your question when you write “But if Cov=0 then X and Y may or may not be independent.” There is a special case theorem about jointly Gaussian random variables but that does not apply here.

Comment: Sir i read a theorem that if 2 random variables are independent if and only if E(XY)=E(X)E(Y). Here there is biimplication, Request your patience .Pls correct me if i understood wrongly

Comment: @Michael sir pls donot use satirical shit. I have posted this because i really do not know. Either u could have ignored it or clarified it. Instead of this satirical story, u should have ignored it. I have started studying and atleast , i feel, i am trying to understand. I am seriously disappointed and irritated with ur attitude.

Comment: Yes i am confused. Pls do not use such language. I could undestand on my own. Of course it may take some time

Comment: You had asked the same question several times, and gotten the same answer, which never sunk in, and you continued asking "Please correct me if I am wrong" when we had already corrected you (please reread my prior comments).  My sarcasm seems to be the only thing that has sunk in and that you have learned from.

Comment: @Michael Ur comment is seriously hurting and condescending.

Comment: @Michael Do u understand all the things in 1 shot. Are u some einstein????. I asked it again and again because it did not sink in my brain. If u are an expert, u would have explained in a different angle.

Comment: @Michael Pls practice some humility. Donot practice intellectual superiority. I mean it.

Comment: I did explain from several different angles. Only one angle sunk in.

Comment: Ok fine then leave it

Comment: Then I am sorry I wrote my sarcastic comment. Your original post correctly showed U and V are uncorrelated, and correctly stated that uncorrelated does not imply independent. I was confused why, over time, you seemed to be "unlearning" that true fact.  You claimed there was a theorem that said uncorrelated $\iff$ independent.  I said there is no such theorem.  You said you had read such a theorem.  You seemed to be changing into a different person from the person who wrote the very clear question in the original post.  I thought my sarcastic comment would be funny, but it was not.

Answer (score 3):

If zero covariance does not imply independence, then why are you trying to calculate the covariance to show independence?  That won't tell you anything useful.  It's like saying that showing a number $x$ is positive does not imply that it is even, but then you are trying to prove $x$ is positive and wondering why this doesn't prove $x$ is even.

Instead, $U = X$ and $V = X^2$ clearly cannot be independent, because knowledge of $X$ immediately tells you the value of $X^2$.  This is trivial.

Comment: Oh yes, but sir then E(UV)=E(U)E(V) is also satisfying right. It means they are indepednent. It is base condition to check wther 2 random variables are indepednet or not. I have recently started studying probability. Pls elaborate. I am not strong conceptually....

Comment: Sir i read a theorem that if 2 random variables are independent if and only if E(XY)=E(X)E(Y). Here there is biimplication, Request your patience .Pls correct me if i understood wrongly

Comment: @NascimentodeCos You are very, very confused.  No such theorem claiming $$\operatorname{E}[XY] = \operatorname{E}[X]\operatorname{E}[Y] \iff X \perp Y$$ exists.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#Expectation_and_covariance and compare with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncorrelated